# How to add select element with dynamic data into datatables.net table?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to add a select dropdown to each of my rows in a dataTable from datables version 1.10.23. Both my table data and select data is coming from an API that returns JSON. I have a separate funtion that gets the select data, builds the selected element in JS and returns the whole element. Normally I can append this to a div no problem, but when trying to add to my data tabel I get: [object HTMLSelectElement] in my table instead of the actual select element.

Code:

```js
    async function buildRentalReturnTable() {

    // table data
    let rentalData = await getRentalDetails();
   
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#rentalReturnTable')) {
        $('#rentalReturnTable').DataTable().destroy();
    }
    // returns whole  selected element with options populated from API 
    let selectElement = await buildStatusDDL();  

    $("#rentalReturnTable").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "data": rentalData,
        "dom": '<"top"i<"clear">><"top d-flex justify-content-between pt-1"lf>rt<"bottom pt-2"p>',
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "scrollY": "50vh",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No results found",
            "sSearch": "Filter Results:"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false
        }],        
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": function (data) {                    
                    return selectElement
                }, "title": "Status"

            },
            { "data": "RentalLPID", "title": "RentalLPID" },
            { "data": "SKU", "title": "SKU" },
            { "data": "Description1", "title": "Description1" },
            { "data": "NextRentalDate", "title": "NextRentalDate" },
        ],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

[UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTMRr.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need the text (string) of the HTML element - not the element itself (which is an object). Try `return selectElement.outerHTML`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) for documentation.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames! That was perfect!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, in case it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need the text (string) of the HTML element - not the element itself (which is an object). Try:

```
return selectElement.outerHTML
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) for documentation.